# CSS, aligning HTML header content with navigation bar

Tags: css, html

i have a header that has one div and two spans inside it:

```
<header class="page_header">

            <div id="title">Some title</div>    
            <span id="user">User: <i>${username }</i></span>
            <span id="search"/><input type="text"><input type="submit" value="Search"/></span>
```

CSS styling for header content is:

```
.page_header {
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 940px;
}
.page_header #user {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.page_header #title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.page_header #search {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Underneat the header is navigation bar. The problem i am having is that my header content is shifted to the right side a little, comparing to navigation bar, and i cant find a way how to fix this. You can see HTML and CSS code here: http://jsfiddle.net/vvozar/QU542/1/

Appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Your header has padding and margin. That affects the width. Search `CSS box model`

Comment: @JoshC ??? The fiddle was given

Comment: @JoshC I was looking at the wrong one. Why don't you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your .page_header class.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/QU542/3/)**

```
.page_header {
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 940px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Or this. Good suggestion. This is probably the cleanest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt know about 'box-sizing' option, still learning. Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Comment: (just to improve answer) 'box-sizing' is not needed if both 'padding' and 'margin' left and right sides are set to zero: `padding: 30px 0; margin:10px 0;`

Comment: @Wlad, that's (obviously) true, but then you don't get left and right padding. From your original code it looked like that you did want the user and search elements to get left/right padding.

Comment: @DanielD - Yes. I was doing these settings yesterday late at night, and probably had that on my mind, to have user and search elements left and right padded. Thanks again for clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In page_header, you need to either (in order of technical preference)

- Remove the width and let it auto size, or
- Set the width to 880px to account for the 60px of padding around the inside or
- Remove the padding and leave the width as 940px.

Your body is also fixed to 940px and technically the inside of page_header only has 880px to work with, so, 940px pushed it outside of its limits, or, in this case, out the right side of the div.

Comment: What about browsers that handle the box model differently? Won't the header be too thin?

Comment: In this case, it seems the primary concern is containing the content above the navigation bar. Auto sizing is probably best. Fixed width to account for the padding would be second best. Lastly, since the OP didn't specify the padding is optional, removing the padding and keeping the original width. I like options; do you like options? I'm going to edit the post.

Comment: What I mean is fixed width + padding in one browser != fixed width + padding in all browsers. OP didn't specify the full width is optional depending on the browser's box model calculation.